# How to find $\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{\bar{\mu}}{\bar{\sigma}^2}\right]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

So this question has found interest in many research problems, but there have been no concrete findings. I want to pose this questions here and take some feedback on how we can solve it. So lets assume you have a Gaussian distribution $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, with $\mu\geq 0$. Let $$\bar{\mu} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$ be the sample mean of $X$, and let $$\bar{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{\mu})^2$$ be its biased estimator (you can assume unbiased estimator too). So now I want to find  $$\mathbb{E} \left[\frac{\bar{\mu}}{\bar{\sigma}^2}\right]$$, i.e. the expectation of sample mean to sample variance. If this is not achievable then then a concentration inequality on $$\mathbb{P} \left(\frac{\bar{\mu}}{\bar{\sigma}^2} - \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2} >\epsilon\right)$$.

My solutions have not found anything solid and I don't think my ways are viable. Anyone who can give any hints on how to solve it would be appreciated.

Comment: Check info about [Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)

Comment: Perhaps you could try in https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, you only need to compute $E[1/\bar \sigma^2]$, so it is enough to compute $E[1/Y]$ for $Y\sim \chi^2_p$, which is well known to be $1/(p-2)$

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach enjoys zero universality...

Comment: $\mathbb E[1/\bar{\sigma}^2] = \infty$ for $n=2$, where $\bar{\sigma}^2 = (X_1 - X_2)^2/4$.